# R Shiny Leaflet: Click on Shape and Zoom to Bounds (using maps package)

Tags: r, shiny, maps, leaflet, mouseevent

For reasons, I am limited to using the "maps" package to generate maps for a leaflet-centered R Shiny app (i.e. I cannot use shape files, rasters, etc. It must be a map object); however, i am running into a wall with some functionality I would like to add.

I'm aiming to allow the user to click on a state in the US and have the app zoom to the bounds of the state. I have found a not-really solution, but what I really need is to use fitBounds() or setMaxBounds(); however, I have no idea how to retrieve the bounds of the state that is selected from the mouse click event.

As of right now, I've found a "pretty good" zoom level for many states using setView(). But, for large states and small states, this just does not work.

Here's the code:

ui.R

```
 library(shiny)
 library(leaflet)

 shinyUI(fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
           tags$style(type = "text/css", "#livemap {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
           leafletOutput("livemap")
      )
 ))
```

server.R

```
 library(shiny)
 library(leaflet)
 library(maps)

 shinyServer(function(input, output){
      output$livemap <- renderLeaflet({
          mapStates <- map("state", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

          leaflet(mapStates) %>%
               addTiles() %>%
               addPolygons(color = "#444444",
                           weight = 1,
                           smoothFactor = 0.5,
                           opacity = 1.0,
                           fillOpacity = 0.5,
                           fillColor = terrain.colors(50, alpha = 1),
                           highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", weight = 2, bringToFront = TRUE))
      })
      observe({
           click <- input$livemap_shape_click
           proxy <- leafletProxy("livemap")
           if(is.null(click))
                return()
           proxy %>% setView(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat, zoom = 7)
      })
 })
```

Comment: this is an idea only: create a new column called `zoomsize` and make your `zoom = click$zoomsize`. Probably have to enter in the data manually (does not seem too arduous if only 50 lines to enter data). Each state will have a specific zoom then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it out. I guess ideally I would like to retrieve the information that would be needed for that zoom for other purposes, but I may be able to find another work-around for that. Thanks!

Comment: leaflet does not seem to like this. After following the steps in your suggestion, leaflet went to the global zoom view. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a huge thanks to @SymbolixAU and @JohnFriel, I was able to achieve the functionality that I was looking for. The key was setting the "layer" ID. The code below allows me to zoom to the appropriate level for each state. Additionally, when the user clicks outside of the shape area, the map is reverted to the default "USA" map and zoom level.

ui.R

```
 library(shiny)
 library(leaflet)

 shinyUI(fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
           tags$style(type = "text/css", "#livemap {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}),
           leafletOutput("livemap")
      )
  ))
```

server.R

```
  library(shiny)
  library(leaflet)
  library(maps)

  shinyServer(function(input, output){
       output$livemap <- renderLeaflet({
            mapStates <- map("state", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
            mapStates$zoom <- c(7.3, 7.1, 7.5, 6.2, 7.2, 9.2, 4.0, 7.0,
                                7.3, 6.5, 7.0, 7.4, 7.5, 7.5, 7.8, 7.4,
                                7.1, 8.3, 8.6, 8.6, 8.6, 7.0, 7.0, 6.7,
                                7.3, 7.2, 7.0, 7.5, 6.6, 7.8, 8.0, 7.0,
                                7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 7.4,
                                7.6, 7.6, 7.2, 7.6, 9.4, 7.8, 7.4, 7.6,
                                6.2, 7.0, 8.0, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 7.3, 7.3,
                                7.3, 7.3, 7.3, 7.6, 7.2, 7.2)
           leaflet(mapStates) %>%
                addTiles() %>%
                addPolygons(color = "#444444",
                            weight = 1,
                            layer = ~mapStates$names,
                            smoothFactor = 0.5,
                            opacity = 1.0,
                            fillOpacity = 0.5,
                            fillColor = terrain.colors(50, alpha = 1),
                            highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black",
                                                                weight = 2,
                                                                bringToFront = TRUE))
       })
       # Observe click on shapes (i.e., states)
       observe({
            click <- input$livemap_shape_click
            if(is.null(click))
                 return()
            idx <- which(mapStates$names == click$id)
            # Get zoom level for the state
            z <- mapStates$zoom[[idx]]
            # Get state name to render new map
            idx <- mapStates$names[[idx]]
            mapInd <- map("county", idx, fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

            leafletProxy("livemap") %>%
                 clearShapes() %>%
                 addPolygons(data = mapInd,
                             color = "#444444",
                             weight = 1,
                             smoothFactor = 0.5,
                             opacity = 1.0,
                             fillOpacity = 0.5,
                             fillColor = terrain.colors(10, alpha = 1)) %>%
                 setView(lng = ((mapInd$range[[1]] + mapInd$range[[2]])/2),
                         lat = ((mapInd$range[[3]] + mapInd$range[[4]])/2),
                         zoom = z)
       })
       # Observe click outside of shapes (i.e., reset the map to the "USA" original)
       observe({
            click <- input$livemap_click
            if(is.null(click))
                 return()
            leafletProxy("livemap") %>%
                 clearShapes() %>%
                 addPolygons(data = mapStates,
                             color = "#444444",
                             weight = 1,
                             layer = ~mapStates$names,
                             smoothFactor = 0.5,
                             opacity = 1.0,
                             fillOpacity = 0.5,
                             fillColor = terrain.colors(50, alpha = 1),
                             highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black",
                                                                 weight = 2,
                                                                 bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
                 setView(lng = ((mapStates$range[[1]] + mapStates$range[[2]])/2),
                         lat = ((mapStates$range[[3]] + mapStates$range[[4]])/2),
                         zoom = 4)
       })

  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @JohnFriel 's suggestion, you can achieve this by setting the zoom level for each state, and then using the click to get that zoom level.

For this to work you need to specify the `layerId` value (in `addPolygons)` so that leaflet knows which shape you've clicked on. You can then access the `zoom` value from this id

See the comments I've added to the code for the changes

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        tags$style(type = "text/css", "#livemap {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
        leafletOutput("livemap")
    )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
    output$livemap <- renderLeaflet({
        mapStates <- map("state", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

        ## chuck on a zoom
        mapStates$zoom <- sample(5:8, size = length(mapStates$name), replace = T)

        leaflet(mapStates) %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addPolygons(color = "#444444",
                                    weight = 1,
                                    layerId = ~mapStates$name,   ## LayerID defined
                                    smoothFactor = 0.5,
                                    opacity = 1.0,
                                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                                    fillColor = terrain.colors(50, alpha = 1),
                                    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", weight = 2, 
                                                                                                            bringToFront = TRUE))
    })

    observe({
        click <- input$livemap_shape_click
        if(is.null(click))
            return()

        ## use the click to access the zoom and set the view according to these
        ## the click$id is now returned with the 'name' of the state
        ## because we specified it in the LayerId argument
        idx <- which(mapStates$name == click$id)
        z <- mapStates$zoom[[idx]]

        leafletProxy("livemap") %>% 
            setView(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat, zoom = z)
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This does achieve the answer that @JohnFriel proposed. A few small, trivial edits: "layerID" should be "layer" and "mapStates$name" should be "mapStates$name". This also gives me an idea of how to achieve my ultimate goal with zooming to the bounds of each state. Thank you!

Comment: @sehock Are you sure it should be just `layer` ? The argument list for `?addPolygons` shows it's `layerId`

Comment: Yes.`layerID` doesn't work for me but `layer` does. My packages are all up-to-date and I am using `R version 3.2.5` for Linux.